# Nuxt + Vuex - How do I break down a Vuex module into separate files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

In the Nuxt documentation ([here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#module-files)) it says 'You can optionally break down a module file into separate files: `state.js`, `actions.js`, `mutations.js` and `getters.js`.'

I can't seem to find any examples of how this is done - lots of breaking down the Vuex store at the root level into `state.js`, `actions.js`, `mutations.js` and `getters.js`, and into individual module files, but nothing about breaking the modules themselves down.

So currently I have:

```
     ├── assets
     ├── components
     └── store
           ├── moduleOne.js
           ├── moduleTwo.js
           └── etc...
```

And what I would like to have is:

```
     ├── assets
     ├── components
     └── store
           └── moduleOne
                 └── state.js
                 └── getters.js
                 └── mutations.js
                 └── actions.js
           └── moduleTwo
                └── etc...
```

To try this out, in `/store/moduleOne/state.js` I have:

```
export const state = () => {
    return {
        test: 'test'
    }
};
```

and in `/store/moduleOne/getters.js` I have:

```
export const getters = {
    getTest (state) {
        return state.test;
    }
}
```

In my component I'm accessing this with `$store.getters['moduleOne/getters/getTest']`

However using the debugger and Vue devtools, it seems like state isn't accessible in the getters file - it seems to be looking for a state in the local file, so `state.test` is undefined.

Attempting to import `state` from my `state.js` file into my `getters.js` file doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone have an example of how they've managed to break the store down like this in Nuxt?

Comment: Good question. Just tried it out and it indeed breaks down my app. Maybe create an issue on https://cmty.app/nuxt/. Seems like either a bug or lack of documentation.

Comment: Example is at https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/test/fixtures/basic/store/foo/blarg ;)

Comment: above answer from @manniL doesn't solve the issue, since the contents of the module directory are simply repeated in the file of the same name in the root of the store

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit more into detail now ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am using nuxt `2.1.0`
If you want to have something like this :

[image: Store module Vuex with Nuxt]

In my `store/index.js`

Make sure you have **namespaced: true**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import apiModule from './modules/api-logic';
import appModule from './modules/app-logic';

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
      appLogic: appModule,
      api: apiModule
    }
  });
};

export default createStore
```

### In moduleOne

In my `store/api-logic/index.js`

```
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

const defaultState = {
  hello: 'salut I am module api'
}

const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
// if in browser, use pre-fetched state injected by SSR
const state = (inBrowser && window.__INITIAL_STATE__) ? window.__INITIAL_STATE__.page : defaultState;

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

In my `store/api-logic/getters.js`

```
export default {
  getHelloThere: state => state.hello
}
```

### In module Two

In my `store/app-logic/index.js`

```
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

const defaultState = {
  appLogicData: 'bonjours I am module Logic'
}

const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
// if in browser, use pre-fetched state injected by SSR
const state = (inBrowser && window.__INITIAL_STATE__) ? window.__INITIAL_STATE__.page : defaultState;

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

In my `store/app-logic/getters.js`

```
export default {
  getAppLogicData: state => state.appLogicData
}
```

Anywhere in the app

```
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
   logicData: 'getAppLogicData',
   coucou: 'getHelloThere'
 })
},
mounted () {
  console.log('coucou', this.coucou) --> salut I am module api
  console.log('logicData', this.logicData) --> bonjours I am module Logic
}
```

**Bonus Point**

If you want to communicate between the modules for example a action in app-logic which trigger something in api-logic.
So app-logic (module one) to api-logic (module two)

*When you specify `root: true` it will start to look at the root of the store.*

In `store/app-logic/actions.js`

```
  callPokemonFromAppLogic: ({ dispatch }, id) => {
    dispatch('callThePokemonFromApiLogic', id, {root:true});
  },
```

In `store/api-logic/actions.js`

```
  callThePokemonFromApiLogic: ({ commit }, id) => {

    console.log('I make the call here')
    axios.get('http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon/' + id).then(response => commit('update_pokemon', response.data))
  },
```

In `store/api-logic/index.js` add another entry

```
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

const defaultState = {
  appLogicData: 'bonjours I am module Logic',
  pokemon: {}
}

const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
// if in browser, use pre-fetched state injected by SSR
const state = (inBrowser && window.__INITIAL_STATE__) ? window.__INITIAL_STATE__.page : defaultState;

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

In `store/api-logic/mutations.js` add the pokemon mutation :p

```
  update_pokemon: (state, pokemon) => {
    state.pokemon = pokemon
  }
```

Anywhere in the app :

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    bidule: 'bidule',
    pokemon: 'getPokemon'
  })
},
mounted() {
  console.log('bidule', this.bidule)
  this.callPokemonFromAppLogic('1') --> the call 
  console.log('the pokemon', this.pokemon.name) --> 'bulbasaur'
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions({
    callPokemonFromAppLogic: 'callPokemonFromAppLogic'
  }),
}
```

At the end your Vue devTool should look like this :)
[image: Vue devTool screenshot store]

And Voilà I hope It was clear.
Code example :

https://github.com/CMarzin/nuxt-vuex-modules

Answer (score 8):

In nuxt version 2.14^  you don't necessary have to create this in your store root index.js file.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import apiModule from './modules/api-logic';
import appModule from './modules/app-logic';

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
      appLogic: appModule,
      api: apiModule
    }
  });
};

export default createStore
```

But instead, you can just leave your root index.js file as default or do what you need. No need to import.

`store/index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
  counter: 0
})

export const mutations = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter++
  }
}

export const actions = {
   async nuxtServerInit({ state, commit }, { req }) {
   const cookies = this.$cookies.getAll() 
   ...
}
```

And this how it looks like, its very simple.

Folder structure

```
store
 ┣ auth
 ┣ utils
 ┣ posts
 ┃ ┗ actions.js
 ┃ ┗ mutations.js
 ┃ ┗ getters.js
 ┃ ┗ index.js
 ┣ index.js
```

Example

`store/posts/index.js` you can just put the state function. You don't need to import the actions, getters and mutations.

```
export const state = () => ({ 
   comments: []
})
```

`store/posts/actions.js`

```
const actions = {
  async getPosts({ commit, state }, obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
       ...
    }
  }
}

export default actions
```

`store/posts/mutations.js`

```
 const mutations = {
    CLEAR_POST_IMAGE_CONTENT: (state) => {
       state.post_image_content = []
    }
 }
 
 export default mutations
```

`store/posts/getters.js`

```
const getters = {
    datatest: (state) => state.datatest,
    headlineFeatures: (state) => state.headlineFeatures,
}

export default getters
```

The effect is same as @CMarzin answer but much cleaner

Comment: Is any solution to isolate one store in one page? I don't need to import checkout store for all pages

Answer (score 0):

## Your issue

Use `default` exports in your files to achieve the desired effect (no named exports except in the `index.js`)

## Example

An example can be found directly in the Nuxt.js test suite (at https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/test/fixtures/basic/store/foo).

If you'd run the `basic` fixture and access the /store page you'll see the following result

[image]

The "repeated" contents in the module itself just show that the split-up values take priority (otherwise `getVal` wouldn't return 10 but 99 and `state.val` wouldn't be 4 but 2).

store.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ baz }}</h1>
    <br>
    <p>{{ $store.state.counter }}</p>
    <br>
    <h2>{{ getVal }}</h2>
    <br>
    <h3>{{ getBabVal }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('foo/bar', ['baz']),
    ...mapGetters('foo/blarg', ['getVal']),
    ...mapGetters('bab', ['getBabVal'])
  }
}
</script>
```